# Retrieve polymorphic associations in Rails from one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Is there a specific way where I can do User.images and get both the user's images and the post's images that belong to that user?

For some reason I can't wrap my head around how to do this best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can avoid polymorphic relationship, simple `has_many` and `belongs_to` will suffice. where :

```
class User ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :images
end

class Post ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But then again I think you wanted to ask about `User.last.images` and not `User.images`

Comment: Yes User.last.images is correct. However, I tried this and only received the images belonging to the User. Even when I added images to the Posts that belong to a User.

Comment: with 'User.last.images' u will receive all the images belonging to the user . Make sure that you have user_id and post_id columns in image table

Comment: Do the posts have to be saved because it's not showing when testing in the rails console?

Comment: `@image = @post.images.build params[:image].merge({ :user_id => current_user.id })`

Comment: It works, the rails c was acting very strange for me

Answer (score 0):

the same can be done through [has_many through associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) as well